# MySQL: NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have these text in my db,

```
categories_posts
categories_news
posts_add
news_add
```

And I don't want to select the rows with `categories`, I use a query something like this,

```
SELECT *
    FROM developer_configurations_cms

    WHERE developer_configurations_cms.cat_id = '1'
    AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_variables LIKE '%parent_id=2%'
    AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_name_unique NOT LIKE '%categories%'
```

but it returns these two in the output as well...

```
categories_posts
categories_news
```

How can I ignore them in my query?

Thanks.

Comment: Am I understand You right? "categories_posts" and "categories_news" are values of "developer_configurations_cms.cfg_name_unique" column?

Comment: in would be enough to say "NOT LIKE 'categories%'", with that values. But this won't solve your problem

Comment: AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_name_unique LIKE '%add'

Comment: @Dalen: "NOT LIKE 'categories%'" - works fine for me. but why won't it solve my problem?

Comment: i guess with that values %categories% and categories% does the same thing. did you query return the correct resultset now?

Comment: @Dalen: yes returns the correct result with categories% :-)

Comment: really weird! I'm going to turn my comment in answerd then

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`categories_posts` and `categories_news` start with substring 'categories_' then it is enough to check that `developer_configurations_cms.cfg_name_unique` starts with 'categories' instead of check if it contains the given substring. Translating all that into a query:

```
SELECT *
    FROM developer_configurations_cms

    WHERE developer_configurations_cms.cat_id = '1'
    AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_variables LIKE '%parent_id=2%'
    AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_name_unique NOT LIKE 'categories%'
```

Comment: Isn't `%` zero or more characters? At least in Oracle that's the case. The OP's original query should work based on what was intended.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why

```
cfg_name_unique NOT LIKE '%categories%'
```

still returns those two values, but maybe exclude them explicit:

```
SELECT *
    FROM developer_configurations_cms

    WHERE developer_configurations_cms.cat_id = '1'
    AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_variables LIKE '%parent_id=2%'
    AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_name_unique NOT LIKE '%categories%'
    AND developer_configurations_cms.cfg_name_unique NOT IN ('categories_posts', 'categories_news')
```

Comment: thanks. cfg_name_unique NOT LIKE 'categories%' - will just work! lol

Comment: the 2 lines are redundant! only one is needed.

Comment: What is theres another name that needs to be ignored like `categories_articles` you have to go back and add that to the query. The accepted answer is much better for future proofing