# return the column that contains only value without white spaces

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

Name column contains space.I tried to fetch the column rows which contains only names and should not return null values and empty values.But it return the column which contain white spaces. I tried:

`select name,id from details where name is not null;`

The above query return the data contains white spaces. how to eliminate the data that contain white space in it?

Comment: did you checkout this answer looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969315/mysql-query-to-return-rows-that-contain-whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use the `NOT LIKE` syntax ; change your query to the following:

```
select name,id from details where name is not null and name not like '% %'
```

you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346859/mysql-not-like) answer.

Comment: there might be somewhere else in your query or code you need to check , because I have tested this.

Comment: you're welcome, try to mark it as the correct answer since it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `trim` function:

```
select name,id from details where name is not null and trim(name) <> '';
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you.

```
select name, id 
from details 
where name is not null and name !=""
```

Comment: Thank you ExDev for formatting my code, As this is my first contribution.
I will take care from next time. :)